# What makes a timelord different?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

Besides the two hearts and regeneration, is there anything that physiologically separates a time-lord from a human being?

Comment: There is the whole "being exposed to the time vortex", which surely must leave some kind of mark. But that might be more of a psychological one.

Comment: Is "Arrogance" enough of an answer?

Comment: @TangoOversway not really, it's not physiological.

Comment: Are you looking for something other than http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Gallifreyan_physiology?  I'm not sure what an answer here would add to that.

Comment: @TonyMeyer That is essentially what I'm after! Thanks for finding it, I didn't think such a list would exist!

Comment: techically "physiology" inlcudes all chemical processes which includes DNA

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Two Hearts that beat at 170 BpM
- Body temperature 59 deg Fahrenheit
- Respiratory bypass system
- Survive Vacuum of space, extreme heat/cold, radiation, electrocution
- Regeneration/healing coma
- Slower aging
- "Rassilon Imprimatur" which allows symbiotic link with the TARDIS
- Minor telepathy
- Control of some internal body functions

More information available from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Lord):

Comment: Many of those attributes are [citation needed] on Wikipedia, and I have doubts about some. For instance, it would be odd for his body temperature to be *that* much lower and not have every single human remark on it the first time he touches them. Are there better sources for this stuff?

Comment: @Geobits [this wiki](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Gallifreyan_physiology) has everything referenced. The low body temperature is from non-TV stories.

Answer (score 12):

A [Time Lord](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Lord) can see all possible timelines.

> Rose Tyler: I can see everything... all that is... all that was... all that ever could be.
>
> The Doctor: But that's what *I* see. All the time. And doesn't it drive you mad?

Time Lords have been shown to exhibit other various mental powers.  All Time Lords can [sense and communicate](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Deadly_Assassin) with other Time Lords.  They can transfer memories to other beings (at the very least, humans) via a [well placed headbutt](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lodger_%28TV_story%29).  The Doctor is shown to have the ability to [manipulate the very memories](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Journey%27s_End) of Donna Noble.

Comment: Most obviously, Time Lords also have a *really precise* time/space sense.  But I'm not sure any of this is *physiological* difference.  Is this actually Gallifreyan biology, or just Vortex exposure?  Rose's comment suggests the latter.

Comment: Right, given viewing the time vortex, possession of a TARDIS, SS, and PP, would a human be that different from a Time Lord?

Comment: Note that Rose is unable to *cope* with her exposure to the Time Vortex (as was Donna), so there is some indication that Gallifreyan brains are different than human brains, it's just never explained how.